# My approach to webderiver

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I started using webdriver not long ago. My approach is as follows:

```
public class PageObjectRepresentationClass {
    protected WebDriver driver;  
    public PageObjectRepresentationClass(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
    }
    public void open(String url){
    driver.get(url);        
    }
    public void close(){
    driver.quit();
    }
     public void fillInputFieldByXPath(String xpath, String value){
    WebElement inputField = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    inputField.clear();
    inputField.sendKeys(value);
    }   
     public PageObjectRepresentationClass clickButtonByClassXPath(String xpath){
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
    return new PageObjectRepresentationClass(driver);
    }
     ...
     // Basically I make here every possible method that deals with my pages
}
```

Now, on my Junit test I have:

```
public class CreateCompanyGermany {

    @Before
    public void pagefactory() {
    page = PageFactory.initElements(new InternetExplorerDriver(), PageObjectRepresentationClass.class); 
    page.open(url);
    }
    @After
    public void closeBrowser(){
    page.close();
    }
    @Test
    public void internetApplying(){
    page.open(url );
    page.chooseOptionFromDropDownMenuById("String", "String");
    page.fillInputFieldByName("String", "String");
    page.fillInputFieldByName("String", "String");
    page.chooseOptionFromDropDownMenuById("String", "String");
    // So from here on I'm just calling methods defined in PageObjectRepresentationClass
}
```

That is my approach of using webdriver. Now what I would like to know is where should benefit  take place in comparing with Selenium 1? I mean if my approach is correct, then only what differs Selenium1 from selenium2/webdriver is fact that in webdriver the one can make sole methods for dealing with pages, so instead of writing

```
    selenium.someMethod(); // derives from selenium API
```

now I will have

```
    page.myMethod();  // in this particular case derives from PageObjectRepresentationClass
```

As far as maintaining of code concerns, I do not see any benefit or am I doing it wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 2 won't offer much improvements for the maintainability of testscripts although there are some classes in the support package which are now available which you can use to implement for instance PageObjects.

Have a look at the [PageFactory](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageFactory) class for instance.

The big difference with selenium 2 is the way it communicates with browsers. Selenium 1 communicates using a javascript server whereas selenium2 webdriver communicates directly with browsers using the browserapi. This has several advantages.

1. It will make tests run a bit faster since they dont have to go through a javascript server
2. You are not bound to the
   (security)restrictions of javascript
   anymore.
3. You don't need (but
       still can use) a server for
       executing your scripts.